# How to get file /etc/init.d/ccpd back?

Tags: printing

I was messing with printer settings.

And one of the steps was:

```
sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults 20
```

It gave an error `ccpd file already exists`.

So without thinking much I did:

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/ccpd
```

Now it says `file ccpd doesn't exist` - probably shouldn't have done that.

So.. How do I get `ccpd` back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ccpd`= Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS ,

then here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
# startup script for Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS (ccpd)

# Provides:         ccpd
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog $network $named
# Should-Start:     $ALL
# Required-Stop:    $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:    2 3
# Default-Stop:     0 1 4 5 6
# Description:      Start Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS


DAEMON=/usr/sbin/ccpd
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/ccpd
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NAME=ccpd
DESC="Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS"

test -f $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case $1 in
  start)
        log_begin_msg "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMON
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  stop)
        log_begin_msg "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  status)
        echo "$DESC: $NAME:" `pidof $NAME`
        ;;
  restart)
        log_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMON
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: ccpd {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

[SOURCE](http://wiki.ubuntu.org.cn/UbuntuHelp:CanonCaptDrv190#Auto_Start_ccpd)

Answer (score 0):

Based off the [installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#Ubuntu_13.10_Install), you can download and extract just the file you need. This is easy enough manually but we can show off and do this in one move and no temporary fluff lying around afterwards:

```
wget -qO- http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100004596/03/Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz \
| tar xzO Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/Src/cndrvcups-capt-2.60-1.tar.gz \
| tar xzO cndrvcups-capt-2.60-1/samples/ccpd \
| sudo tee /etc/init.d/ccpd >/dev/null
```

`wget` downloads, `tar` extract the nested source archive and passed that to another instance of `tar` that reads out the file, which passes into `tee` to write into the right file as root.

**Note**: this gives a significantly different result from NikTh's. I'm not sure if this is just based on an updated version of the script but there you go, here's the version you'd currently get with my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# startup script for Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS (ccpd)

if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
    if [ -f /etc/slackware-version ]; then
        SYS_F="SL"
    else
        . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions 
        SYS_F="RH"
    fi
elif [ -x /sbin/startproc ]; then
    SYS_F="Su"
elif [ -x /sbin/start-stop-daemon ]; then
    SYS_F="De"
fi

DAEMON=/usr/sbin/ccpd
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/ccpd

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin

ccpd_start ()
{
    echo -n "Starting ${DAEMON}: "

    if [ "$SYS_F" = "RH" ]; then    
        daemon ${DAEMON}
        [ "$?" = "0" ] && touch ${LOCKFILE}
        echo "."
    elif [ "$SYS_F" = "Su" ]; then
        startproc ${DAEMON}
        echo "."
    elif [ "$SYS_F" = "De" ]; then
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec ${DAEMON}
        echo "."
    else
        `${DAEMON}`
    fi
}

ccpd_stop ()
{
    echo -n "Shutting down ${DAEMON}: "

    if [ "$SYS_F" = "De" ]; then
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --signal 15 --exec ${DAEMON}
        echo "."
    elif [ "$SYS_F" = "SL" ]; then
        kill -KILL `pidof ${DAEMON}`
        [ "$?" = "0" ] && rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
        echo 
    else
        killproc ${DAEMON}
        [ "$?" = "0" ] && rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
        echo    
    fi
}


case $1 in

    start)
        ccpd_start
        ;;

    stop)
        ccpd_stop
        ;;

    status)
        echo "${DAEMON}:" `pidof ${DAEMON}`
        ;;

    restart)
        ccpd_stop
        ccpd_start
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: ccpd {start|stop|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```